# Решение для отмены внесённых изменений в БД

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

Пишу на Python, вид/тип/разработчик СУБД не важен, готов рассмотреть любые варианты.

В моей программе необходимо реализовать возможность отмены внесённых пользователем изменений. На данном этапе я реализовал это так:

1. Перед вставкой значений в таблицу происходит из сравнение по идентификатору строки.
2. Если есть совпадения, то происходит сравнение значений в столбцах.
3. Значения, которые уже есть в БД, переносятся в отдельную таблицу (OldValuesTable).
4. Новые значения вставляются в целевую таблицу с заменой методом Update.
5. При необходимости, можно восстановить исходные значения, используя OldValuesTable.

Есть ли уже готовое подобное решение данной задачи? Или я изобретаю велосипед?
[image: Пример как происходит вставка значений]

Comment: Ну наверное разве что триггер повесить на таблицу и пусть он старые значения сохраняет и при изменениях.

Comment: *Есть ли уже готовое подобное решение данной задачи?* В некоторых СУБД - есть.

Comment: Используйте timeline. То есть таблица - одна. Никаких UPDATE - исключительно INSERT. Актуальная запись может просто определяться по штампу времени создания. Можно для этого завести отдельное поле - тогда триггер корректирует значение поля актуальности у предыдущей записи. В этом случае имеет смысл партиционировать таблицу по полю актуальности, соответственно все запросы, работающие с актуальными записями, не будут дёргать партицию устаревших записей. В то же время несложно восстановить состояние на любой момент времени.

Comment: @Akina Да, кстати, популярный вариант

Comment: Некоторые СУБД имеют встроенные средства работы с timeline. Вот, например, реализация, имеющаяся в MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-tables/